# Get peak amount of memory used by a C program

Tags: c, windows, memory, memory-management

I recently started fiddling with programming in C. What I need to do is find the maximum amount of memory used by a program throughout the lifetime of the process. How can I do this easily on Windows? Basically a tool in the form of:

```
> memoryused myprogram.exe
> peak amount of memory used: 36 bytes
```

I don't really need to track memory usage at any given time during the execution of the process.

Answer (score 1):

for this you need use [`GetProcessMemoryInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683219(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use the CRT Debug Heap to take snapshots of the heap state, including the amount of memory used. This does not report the maximum heap amount used but by taking snapshots at regular intevals, you might get an indication of your heap usage. This neither reports the maxmum amount of stack used.

See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h3z85t43.aspx